# rails 3.2.1 and mysql where condition with nil issue (it toggles in no record and proper result)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I run the following query in rails console 
On first run it returns 7 rows and 2nd run it returns 0 rows, its keeps toggling...

```
@site.site_pages.published\
.where(:is_visible => true,:parent_id => nil,:lang_parent_id => nil)\
.order("position ASC")

=> [ARRAY OF RECORDS]
-- {Returns 7 rows}

@site.site_pages.published\
.where(:is_visible => true,:parent_id => nil,:lang_parent_id => nil)\
.order("position ASC")

=> []
-- {Returns 0 rows}
```

As a fix/work around I tried this, which worked fine, but need to know the root cause

```
@site.site_pages.published\
.where(:is_visible => true,:parent_id => [nil, ''],:lang_parent_id => [nil, ''])\
.order("position ASC")
```

NOTE: If i run the to_sql query in mysql, it works fine, so considering nothing to do with mysql version etc, but its 5.6.

Comment: Can you show your `published` scope definition? And confirm that `to_sql` is the same both before and after running the query?

Comment: yes, atleast rails console says both sql are same.
and scope is ->

"scope :published,  where(:status => PUBLISHED)"